# Resize UIView for CoreText

Tags: uiview, core-text

Im working on an app where depending on which button is pressed, a different text file is loaded into a `UIView` using coretext. The different text files vary greatly in size - is there anyway I can set the UIView to resize itself depending on which file has been called? At the moment my solution is setting it to accommodate the largest text file, but it looks a little odd when the smallest text file is called and the screen can scroll down through alot of blank space. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Depending how you are rendering the text, you could possibly use some of the NSString [sizeWithFont](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) methods to determine how much space it is going to take up and then size the the UIView to match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `CTFramesetterRef` from your text (Attributed string), then use `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` function to calculate height of text drawing for your view's width, update view's size and draw core text on it using `CTFrameRef`.

For Core text drawing size sample source code refer [EGOTextView.m](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView/blob/master/EGOTextView/EGOTextView.m) -approximate line numbers:- 292 to 352.